# Data not inserting in custom table with code in functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a custom HTML form in WordPress which inserts data into a custom table. I have written code in the functions.php file to insert data.

The HTML code is as below:

```
<form id="regForm" method="POST" action="">
```

My PHP function is as below:

```
function xx_data_insert() {
    session_start();
    require_once "wp-load.php";
    require_once "dbconfig.php";
    global $wpdb, $current_user;

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $table_name = 'xx_table';

    //Form variables defined too many to add here
    //insert statement
    $flag = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
        (field1,field2,field3) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",
        $field1, 
        $field2, 
        $field3
    ));

    if ($flag) {
        echo "<script>";
        echo " alert('Data saved successfully');
            window.location.href='".site_url('http://xxx/xxx')."';
            </script>";
        exit();
    }

    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) xx_data_insert();
```

When the submit button is clicked, there is no error. The page just refreshes. How do I check if the code is even going to the if statement? Any way to trap ?

David

Comment: Do you have a complete form? More than just the opening tag?

Comment: Yes I do have a complete form. I just thought this would be the most relevant part.

Comment: @Maxime - `functions.php` is a file that will be included on all page requests in WP, so you don't need to post to that file specifically.

Comment: _"How do I check if the code is even going to the if statement?"_ - Have you checked your database to see if anything is inserted? You could also put: `echo 'Foo'; exit;'` in your if-statement. if you submit the form and see "foo" in the screen, the if-statement works. You should add the code for the complete form as well.

Comment: @DavidD'Lima The full form - at least the opening, closing and submit-parts of it are relevant.

Comment: @Qirel 24 Have added the relevant code

Comment: Just making sure, the `action` field in the form opening tag is filled right? and that you're leaving it empty on purpose?

Comment: @Kevinfu the action field is blank as I have added the php code in functions.php and the if statement will check if the form is submitted.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson putting echo foo exit did not work. the message does not show at all.

Comment: Guys any help would be great!!!

Comment: If you check your servers error log, you'll probably see some "syntax error"-messages. `$wpdb->prepare((field1,field2,field3)` is not just missing the opening quote before the query, it's also missing the `INSERT INTO tableName`.

Comment: Also, when the code is properly indented, you can see that you also never close your function and the code that calls the function is also inside the function.

Comment: From the `require_once "wp-load.php";  require_once "dbconfig.php";` I am going to assume this is a standalone file, not a plugin/etc. Why not use basic PDO/MySQLi? The WP functionality seems redundant

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Having fixed the above errors, the code still does not work !! Is there something wrong in the process that I am following?

Comment: @ggdx, this is a standalone file.

Comment: Please check your servers error log to see it there are any errors in there.

Answer (score 0):

$flag = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
        (field1,field2,field3) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",
        $field1, 
        $field2, 
        $field3
    ));

check this (field1,field2,field3) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", starting quote is missing